# CoreCLR solution for having the code know whether an ASP.NET 5 application is self hosted or running on IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, owin, asp.net-core, coreclr

As a part of fiddling around with ASP.NET 5, I've been exploring into the CoreCLR and can't work out how the code can discover whether it's running on IIS or self hosting via the OWIN spec.

I could bring in `System.Diagnostics` and investigate the current process (`klr` for self host and `iisexpress` or `W3wp` for IIS)  but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it solely using CoreCLR. Possibly through inspecting the request pipeline somehow and see that IIS is a part of it?

Answer (score 0):

in the samples of the MusicStore repository I see a line that can be useful :

```
bool isMono = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null;
```

here's the sample code https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs

Comment: `Type.GetType()` is unavailable to the CoreCLR.

Comment: and how do you think the asp.net team uses it ? it's probably on another (new) package. Checkout the project code.

Comment: Nevermind, you're correct, even though VS 2015 CTP 6 tells me otherwise before compilation unless I explicitly only have Core selected in project.json. That solution could work, but I can't find the correct string for the CoreCLR runtime (even if running on Windows). The closest I could find is from [here](http://aakinshin.net/en/blog/dotnet/jit-version-determining-in-runtime/).